# Android - Google Maps integration empty activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mapview, android-maps

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps API v2 into secondary activity(that is started from the main activity). I obtained the API key and followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api), but when the activity that contains Google Maps is started, it  shows only the blank tiles. This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dimacroitori.supermarket"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
     android:required="true"/>



<permission
      android:name="com.examplemapsactivity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.examplemapsactivity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.dimacroitori.supermarket.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="BasketActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MapsActivity"></activity>

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MapsActivity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_act);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub//
}

}
```

map_act.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and this is the error from logcat when i'm trying to start activity:

```
12-18 16:09:27.911: E/Google Maps Android API(14414): Google Maps application is missing.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does your phone that you are testing on have Google Maps installed?

Comment: thanks man, you saved my day... i forgot that i installed custom rom without google maps...

Comment: you have to extend something else at activity , won t be helpful to put MapView and extend MapActivity ?